# how to count consecutive number of ones given a decimal number?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def decToBin(n):
    x=str(bin(n))
    x=x[2:]
    return x

def result(x):
    print(len(max(x.split('0'))))
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input().strip())
    decToBin(n)
    result(x)
```

I have tried this code but  i  am getting an error saying undefined "x"
I want to know what is wrong in this code.

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues in your code.

1. You aren't returning anything from decToBin function, you should put this at the end of the function:
   `return x`
2. You aren't storing the result of decToBin function anywhere, you can either store it in a variable or put decToBin directly in the result function like this:
   `result(decToBin(n))`
3. Your code is not formatted according to [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) in some places, I highly recommend you to read it and use it as it should be always used when programming in Python

I'm also not sure if this is what you wanted to do according to your question title

Here is the final code:

```
def decToBin(n):
    x = str(bin(n))
    x = x[2:]
    return x


def result(x):
    print(len(max(x.split('0'))))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input().strip())
    result(decToBin(n))
```

Comment: after adding `return x` in my code it still says ** x is undefined **.  about the indentation that was a typo and the final result should convert the decimal to binary and count consecutive 1's in the binary

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the value `x` is defined in your method `decToBin`, but never returned. So it is only valid inside of that method.

```
def decToBin(n):
    x=str(bin(n))
    x=x[2:]
    return x

def result(x):
    print(len(max(x.split('0'))))
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input().strip())
    x = decToBin(n)
    result(x)
```

EDIT:
But your code is not counting the ones in a decimal number, but in the binary representation of the number.

Comment: after adding `return x` in my code there is an error saying **"x" is not defined** i think there might be problem with defining a local and global variable (not sure). please look into this.

Comment: @flash could you share the current state? Is the indentation from the question the same as in your code? Maybe this causes a problem. I don't know why it would make difficulties.

Comment: it was a typo(my bad ) now i have updated my question and it still says not defined 'x'

Comment: @flash Get rid of the single quotes `'` in the return statement: instead of `return 'x'`, use `return x`. See my code sample. Your function will always return the String "x", but not the variable x.

Comment: @flash Also, you need to change the `if __name__ == '__main__':` section like in my answer: assign the returned value from `decToBin(n)` to `x`: `x = decToBin(n)`.

Comment: yeah it worked the problem was i did not assign `x=decToBin(n)`

Comment: @flash yeah there were only these two minor issues in your code.